# Getting error when compiling glibc-2.22 on RHEL 5.11

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

I am trying to port some software into RHEL 5.11, which requires glibc greater than 2.11. When I am compiling glibc 2.22 (or any other version greater than 2.11) on RHEL 5.11, I am getting the following error.

```
gcc iconv_close.c -c -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline  -O3 -Wall -Werror -Wno-error -Wno- 
error=undef -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -g -Wstrict- 
prototypes   -fPIC   -ftls-model=initial-exec      -I../include - 
I/root/river/22102022/glibc-2.22/build/iconv  -I/root/river/22102022/glibc-2.22/build  -I../sysdeps/unix/   sysv/linux/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../  sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/include -I../   sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet      -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/  x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu/include     -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/   ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/    ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I.       -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include /root/river/22102022/glibc-2.22/build/libc-modules.h     -DMODULE_NAME=libc -include ../include/libc-symbols.h  -DPIC -DSHARED     -o /root/river/   22102022/glibc-2.22/build/iconv/iconv_close.os -MD -MP -MF /root/river/22102022/glibc-2.22/build/   iconv/iconv_close.os.dt -MT /root/river/22102022/glibc-2.22/build/iconv/iconv_close.os

make[2]: *** [/root/river/22102022/glibc-2.22/build/iconv/gconv_conf.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gconv_db.c: Assembler messages:
gconv_db.c:737: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:740: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:743: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:746: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:777: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:780: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:750: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:753: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:769: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:772: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:797: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:800: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:811: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
gconv_db.c:814: Error: CFI instruction used without previous .cfi_startproc
```

I am using gcc 5.2.0.

Can someone please suggest me where should I look for solving this issue?

Comment: Compiling the C library is a major undertaking as it has a tight dependency on the toolchain version. Not to mention, you will have a very hard time running this software with two C libraries lying around. Not saying it is impossible though...

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting that far; glibc 2.22 requires headers from kernel 2.6.32 or later, and I don't think RHEL5.11 ships with a recent enough kernel.